# Multiple count columns on a single statement grouped by distinct username

Tags: mysql, sql

Fairly new to SQL and having some troubles with a particular statement.

Here is some sample data:

```
date       | username
2016-01-01 | JIM
2016-01-01 | BOB
2016-01-01 | BOB
2016-01-02 | JIM
2016-01-03 | JIM
2016-01-03 | JIM
2016-01-03 | BOB
```

What I am trying to do is count each distinct date per username except I want each date on its own column with an individual count per date per username.

I will be supplying each individual date via PHP and was hoping you could return the following table in a single SQL Query:

```
username | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-03
JIM      | 1          | 1          | 2
BOB      | 2          | 0          | 1
```

So far all I can achieve is a list of dates, usernames and the count per day per username:

```
SELECT date,
       haulier,
       count(*)
FROM demo
WHERE date >= '2016-01-01' AND
      date <= '2016-01-03'
GROUP BY date,
         haulier
```

Regards

Comment: If you have an open range of dates, then you would probably need dynamic SQL for this.  Google pivot MySQL dynamic.

Comment: As you will be processing the results in PHP you could settle with the current query (but replace `COUNT(*)` by `COUNT(DISTINCT date)`) and just build an array in PHP at the time you are getting the results. Probably easier than meddling with "dynamic SQL".

Comment: Thank you for these comments, I have played around with pivot to get exactly the table results I needed. Is there any reason DROP VIEW and re-running the CREATE VIEW PIVOT command is a bad idea, I expect this command to be run once per week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.username,
       sum(date = '2016-01-01') as cnt_20060101,
       sum(date = '2016-01-02') as cnt_20060102,
       sum(date = '2016-01-03') as cnt_20060103
from sample s
group by s.username;
```

If you don't know the specific dates, then you need to use dynamic SQL.  You can Google "MySQL dynamic pivot" to see examples of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with using pivot.

```
drop view IF EXISTS username_count;

create view username_count as (
  select
    username,
    case when date = "2016-01-01" then username end as monday,
    case when date = "2016-01-02" then username end as tuesday,
    case when date = "2016-01-03" then username end as wednesday,
    case when date = "2016-01-04" then username end as thursday,
    case when date = "2016-01-05" then username end as friday
  from table_name
);

drop view IF EXISTS username_count_pivot;

create view username_count_pivot as (
  select
    username,
    count(monday) as monday,
    count(tuesday) as tuesday,
    count(wednesday) as wednesday,
    count(thursday) as thursday,
    count(friday) as friday
  from username_count
  group by username
);

select * from username_count_pivot;
```

This returns the following table:

```
username | monday | tuesday | wednesday | thursday | friday
JIM      | 1      | 1       | 2         | 0        | 0
BOB      | 2      | 0       | 1         | 0        | 0
```